# Is $\Delta C_c^\infty$ a dense subset of $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis, potential-theory

I'm struggling to obtain some density result. It is well known that $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is dense in $L^p (\mathbb{R}^d)$ for $1\leq p<\infty$.

It is well known that for $\lambda>0$, $(\lambda -\Delta) C_c^\infty$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ for $1\leq p <\infty$.

Proof of this fact requires maximum principle and Hahn-Banach theorem, and Riesz representation theorem. (Stated in Krylov's Elliptic and Parabolic equation in Sobolev spaces)

I'm wondering whether $\Delta C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$  is dense in $L^p (\mathbb{R}^d)$.

I tried by using Newtonial potential, but I fail to obtain the desired result because I found $C^\infty$ function, but I cannot make a sequence of $C^\infty$ functions with compact support. Even I tried cut-off method, I cannot guarantee the fact.

Comment: Not dense for $p=1$: the Laplacian of a compactly supported function integrates to zero. Dense for $p=2$, considering the Fourier transform. I think it's dense for $1<p<\infty$.

Comment: @Bookend Indeed. Now in general, when the cases $p=1$ and $p=2$ are different, the case $1<p<\infty$ is "always" like the case $p=2$. QED. Of course some might say that was somewhat lacking in rigor, heh-heh...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No for $p=1$, yes for $1<p<\infty$.

If $\phi\in \Delta C^\infty_c$ then $\int\phi=0$; this shows that $\Delta C^\infty_c$ is not dense in $L^1$.

One might think at first that this shows the same thing for other $p$, but it doesn't, because the integral is not a bounded linear functional. Suppose from now on that $1<p<\infty$.

Suppose that $K\in L^1\cap L^\infty$, and for $\delta>0$ define $$K_\delta(x)={\delta^d}K\left( \delta x\right).$$If $\phi\in C^\infty_c$ then $||K_\delta*\phi||_1\le||K||_1||\phi||_1$ and $||K_\delta*\phi||_\infty\le c\delta^d$, hence $$||K_\delta*\phi||_p\to0\quad(\delta\to0).$$

Now say $K=c\chi_{B(0,1)}$, where $c$ is chosen so that $\int K=1$. Say $G$ is the Green's function. Then $$K_\delta*G(x)=G(x)\quad(|x|>1/\delta),$$so if $\phi\in C^\infty_c$ and we set $$\psi_\delta=(\phi-\phi*K_\delta)*G$$then $\psi_\delta\in C^\infty_c$. So $\phi-\phi*K_\delta\in \Delta C^\infty_c$, and if $||f-\phi||_p<\epsilon$ then $||f-(\phi-\phi*K_\delta)||_p<2\epsilon$ for small enough $\delta$.

Comment: Sorry. Can you explain why $\phi -\phi *K_\delta $ is in $\Delta C^\infty_c$? I know that $\Delta (\phi - \phi*K_\delta) = \psi_\delta$ but why $\phi *K_\delta$ is $C^\infty_c$?

Comment: @WillKwon Not sure which part you don't get. (i) $C^\infty_c*L^1_{loc}\subset C^\infty$, so $\psi_\delta\in C^\infty$. (ii) Since $K_\delta*G(x)=G(x)$ for $|x|>1/\delta$ and $\phi$ has compact support it follows that $\psi_\delta$ has compact support.

Comment: I'm sorry. I was confused the direction. Thank you for explanation.

Comment: @WillKwon Oh. You say you know that $\Delta(\phi-\phi*K_\delta)=\psi_\delta$. Maybe that was a typo; if not then that's the problem: Actually $\Delta\psi_\delta=\phi-\phi*K_\delta$.

Comment: At that time moment, I got confused. Now, I understand all of your arguments. 

Again, Thanks you for your gentle answer and explanation.